# CURL error "Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x...)"

Tags: curl

I'm having a PHP script open and parse a number of RSS-feeds via curl. Attempting to read one of them, `CURLOPT_STDERR` returned the following error:

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558820d06dc0)
... and so on for more than a hundred lines
```

An hour later I get the same error, only the number behind "transfer" has changed. Another hour later the feed can be read successfully (without any changes to my code).

What does that error mean?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is not an error message, it was an *informational message* in the log output - and one that was left there by mistake and has since been removed. Gone in 7.64.1 and later.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, my hosting provider has installed an outdated version of CURL? And still, what does that message mean? Or was it removed because it is meaningless? There must have been something going on, because after all that was the first time in eleven years of reading that and many other feeds that I got that message.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis It was an accident. You never saw it before because it was only introduced in 7.64.0, only about a year before your post (and it takes some time for these updates to filter down into distros and to get installed). Your hosting provider is not installing outdated versions: quite the contrary! It sounds like they're keeping well up-to-date with the latest changes, good _and_ bad. ;) That also means they should get the fix (in 7.64.1) quickly.

Answer (score 5):

It was a mistake during merge of `curl` code:

- https://curl.se/mail/lib-2019-02/0053.html

I see garbage because of Debian 10 v7.64.0:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=941328

Comment: Not exactly. The mistake was that the message was used for debugging an issue and it accidentally landed in the master branch and nobody noticed/reported it until after we had released that curl version.